# Is this the right way of passing an array of a class to a method in another class

Tags: c++, arrays, pass-by-reference

I need to pass an array of  gameEntity to a method in Collision Class

```
Class Game{
   public: GameEntity *positions[48];
           void DoAction();
           Collision *col;
  }
```

In Game.cpp

```
  void GameEntity::DoAction(){

      col = new Collision(positions[0]);
   }
```

The class that accepts the array of gamentity in its constructor

```
 class Collision{

    public:
      Collision(GameEntity * positions)

   }
```

In Collision.cpp

```
  Collision::Collision(GameEntity  *springBalls)
   {

          for(int i = 0 ; i< 49; i++)

         {
           cout<<springBalls[0]<<endl

         }
  }
```

Comment: An array of a class? Is this some new C++ feature with neat reflection tricks I don't know of?

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: i suspect you mean `springBalls[i]` and that you want `Collision::Collision(GameEntity  **springBalls)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This declaration,

```
GameEntity *positions[48];
```

is an array of 48 pointers to `GameEntity`.

I remember that by way of the standard `main` signature.

A formal argument accepting that can be

```
GameEntity** a
```

or it can be e.g.

```
GameEntity* (&a)[48]
```

where the latter receives the array by reference, but for that reason needs to have the array size hardwired.

---

As a general comment, wherever practical prefer standard library abstractions such as `std::array` and `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `std::vector`

Problem 1:

```
col = new Collision(positions[0]);
```

Pass in the pointer, not dereferene to first element

```
col = new Collision(positions);
```

Problem 2:

You allocated 48 GameEntity:s (indexed 0-47). But you try to access [48]

```
for(int i = 0 ; i< 49; i++)
```

Problem 3:

```
GameEntity *positions[48];
```

is an array of pointers. Therefore Collision::Collision should take an argument of type GameEntity**

Answer (score 0):

You would do something like this for the Collision object:

Collision::Collision(GameEntity** springBalls) { }

But then your springBalls would have to be an array of 48 GameEntity objects.